# Xcode has encountered an unexpected error (0xC00D) Permission denied

Tags: iphone, permission-denied, organizer

Xcode can't access my iPhone 4, nor another iPhone 4 nor iPad 2.
I've tried restaring the devices, mac and reinstalling Xcode two times from the App Store.
I've also tried setting chmods of everything to 777, removing the 5.1 sdk, but nothing helps.

The error that I keep getting in the organizer is:

Xcode has encountered an unexpected error (0xC00D)
Permission denied, at ‘/SourceCache/DTDeviceKit/DTDeviceKit-1196/DTDeviceKit/DTDeviceKit_Utilities.m:854’

Please help.

I've started the same topic on Apple dev forums:
https://devforums.apple.com/message/650466#650466

Comment: try re-installing iPhone drivers. Delete them and then fresh install. I think your device is not recognized. Try to go in that direction

Comment: What iPhone drivers are you talking about?

Comment: something like this : http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/1529

Comment: I'm on mac ;] not on PC.